# addEventListener vs onclick when callback function changes

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

My HTML code is below:
My question is, why does it show "before" dialog when clicking Button 1, but show "after" dialog when clicking Button 2?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button id="b1">Button 1</button>
        <button id="b2" onclick="OnClick();">Button 2</button>

        <script>
            var OnClick = function(){alert("before");};
            document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click", OnClick);
            var OnClick = function(){alert("after");};
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/72chrqnf/

Comment: @Ivar that's probably not the problem though. `OnClick` isn't being set to another value in the first place.

Comment: @LucaKiebel I'm not sure I follow you. If a reference was passed instead of the value, the "after" would've been shown. But that is not the case here.

Comment: Because this happens, step by step: 

1. The page is loaded
2. The page is being parsed/evaluated
3. The <script> is evaluated BEFORE HTML
4. OnClick #1 is defined 
5. event listener (OnClick #1) is added on `#b1` element
6. OnClick #2 is defined (overwrites previous OnClick value)
7. <script> has completed being evaluated
8. HTML starts being evaluated event listener 9. (OnClick #2) is added on `#b2` element

Comment: @Ivar Thanks a lot. I understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause `OnClick` gets evaluated to the first function before you change the variable pointing to a different function. When this line gets evaluated:

```
  document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click", OnClick);
```

it evaluates `OnClick` and results in:

```
 document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click", [a reference pointing to the function])
```

and therefore changing `OnClick` does not affect it afterwards.